# Where gem path supervisor see?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, supervisord

I want to exec sinatra app from supervisord. sinatra gem is installed in `/home/lastcat(<-my username)/.rbenv/shims/gem`.
I wrote following sinatra.conf.

```
[program:sinatra]
user=lastcat
environment=PATH="/home/lastcat/.rbenv/shims:/home/lastcat/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"/home/lastcat/Documents/tmp/app.rb
command=ruby /home/lastcat/Documents/tmp/app.rb
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/sinatra.log
```

but, when I exec `sudo supervisorctl start sinatra`, this error happen.

```
    from /home/lastcat/Documents/tmp/app.rb:1:in `<main>'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- sinatra (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

I suspected supervisor cannot see gem path for some reason. I change `command` to `which ruby` and `which gem`, and confirm their result.But they are `/home/lastcat/.rbenv/shims/ruby`and`/home/lastcat/.rbenv/shims/gem`.

next, I change `command` to `gem list`.Then, output is,

```
bigdecimal (1.2.4)
bundler (1.10.6)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.8.1)
minitest (4.7.5)
psych (2.0.5)
rake (10.1.0)
rdoc (4.1.0)
test-unit (2.1.2.0)
```

It is unexpected result.Result of `gem list` by user:lastcat,

```
bigdecimal (1.2.0)
bundler (1.10.6)
~
sinatra (1.4.6)
~
```

ofcourse, result of `which gem`and`which ruby` by normaly execed by lastcat, equal to previous them.
In other words, supervisor see another path when `which gem` and when `gem list` I don't understand this phenomenon.

post sctripts:  result of `sudo gem list` is equal to `gem list` by supervisor.It exec command in root enviroment……?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set GEM_PATH in environment:

```
environment=GEM_PATH="YOUR_GEM_PATH"
```

And print ENV in IRB to find your GEM_PATH.